# Virtualbox static IP to windows VM on ubuntu host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp, static-ip

I am trying to setup a windows VM on Ubuntu host using Virtual box. Since I would be running a SQL server database on the windows VM I am trying to setup a static IP on that VM. In order to do that I followed the instruction available [here](http://coding4streetcred.com/blog/post/VirtualBox-Configuring-Static-IPs-for-VMs).

Below are my Virtualbox Network configurations for host-only adapter:

[image] 
[image]

Here is my Network configuration for windows VM:

[image]

and lastly here is my configuration for the windows network adapter where I have assinged the static IP

[image]

When I run ifconfig, this is what I get for `vboxnet1` adapter on my ubuntu host

```
vboxnet1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:01  
inet addr:192.168.57.1  Bcast:192.168.57.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::800:27ff:fe00:1/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:15853 (15.8 KB)
```

Even after this when I ping the assigned static IP I am not getting any response:

```
> ping 192.168.57.103
PING 192.168.57.103 (192.168.57.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.57.103 ping statistics ---
942 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 946463ms
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything? Let me know if you need any other information that would be helpful for debugging this issue.

*** Edited with solution ***

As per @cslotty's response below the problem was that the ICMP echo port was blocked in windows firewall. enabling that port fixed the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the subnet mask to 255.255.255.255! You're not configuring that Windows VM to use a whole subnet, but only one address, right?

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/

After all settings are correct, the Windows firewall could be the blocking issue.

Comment: you are right I am planning on using that windows VM to use only a single IP and not the whole subnet so I changed the mask to 255.255.255.255. But unforunately that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried pinging _out_ of that VM?

Comment: And you could try to set the default gateway in your Windows network config, too, otherwise it might not have any route.

Comment: I am able to ping the host from the guest. Not the other way round though.

Comment: Then maybe check the firewall in Windows :-)

Comment: You were right! ICMP port for echo request was blocked by default! I don't know how that happened. Enabling that port fixed the issue. Thanks!